# How to create an invoice entity using the QuickBooks Online Java SDK

Tags: java, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I'm referring to version v3 (2.2.1) of the SDK. I'm trying to figure out what I need to do to create an invoice. My issue is not any errors or connection issues, it's just that the docs seem to be poor and there's no examples. So what I have is:

```
BatchOperation batch= new BatchOperation();
Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
invoice.set...
...
batch.addEntity(invoice, OperationEnum.CREATE, "bID");
```

The problem is that I just don't understand how the *many* setter methods for the `Invoice` entity would correspond to a general invoice e.g. the ID, customer identifer etc.

If anyone has done this before could you give me an example of the kinds of setters that I might want to use for a generic invoice. My main problem here is that the explanations for all the `Invoice` setters (and getters) in the JavaDoc are like:

```
setAllowIPNPayment(Boolean value) 
       Sets the value of the allowIPNPayment property.
```

...and they're all like that e.g. `Sets the value of the [X] property`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PFB one sample payload.

**Request**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <Invoice xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
        <Line>
            <Amount>15</Amount>
            <DetailType>SalesItemLineDetail</DetailType>
            <SalesItemLineDetail>
                <ItemRef name="Hours">2</ItemRef>
            </SalesItemLineDetail>
        </Line>
        <CustomerRef name="Hours">2</CustomerRef>
    </Invoice>
```

**Response**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2014-04-30T07:35:49.705-07:00">
    <Invoice domain="QBO" sparse="false">
        <Id>16</Id>
        <SyncToken>0</SyncToken>
        <MetaData>
            <CreateTime>2014-04-30T07:35:49-07:00</CreateTime>
            <LastUpdatedTime>2014-04-30T07:35:49-07:00</LastUpdatedTime>
        </MetaData>
        <DocNumber>1003</DocNumber>
        <TxnDate>2014-04-30</TxnDate>
        <CurrencyRef name="Australian Dollar">AUD</CurrencyRef>
        <Line>
            <Id>1</Id>
            <LineNum>1</LineNum>
            <Amount>15.00</Amount>
            <DetailType>SalesItemLineDetail</DetailType>
            <SalesItemLineDetail>
                <ItemRef name="Hours">2</ItemRef>
            </SalesItemLineDetail>
        </Line>
        <Line>
            <Amount>15.00</Amount>
            <DetailType>SubTotalLineDetail</DetailType>
            <SubTotalLineDetail/>
        </Line>
        <CustomerRef name="abc">2</CustomerRef>
        <DueDate>2014-05-30</DueDate>
        <GlobalTaxCalculation>NotApplicable</GlobalTaxCalculation>
        <TotalAmt>15.00</TotalAmt>
        <PrintStatus>NeedToPrint</PrintStatus>
        <EmailStatus>NotSet</EmailStatus>
        <Balance>15.00</Balance>
        <Deposit>0</Deposit>
        <AllowIPNPayment>false</AllowIPNPayment>
        <AllowOnlinePayment>false</AllowOnlinePayment>
        <AllowOnlineCreditCardPayment>false</AllowOnlineCreditCardPayment>
        <AllowOnlineACHPayment>false</AllowOnlineACHPayment>
    </Invoice>
</IntuitResponse>
```

You can use the above setter using java sdk. It will create a valid Invoice.
Please use IDs of valid referenced objects (Item and Customer)

Doc Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/invoice

**Update**

```
void createInvoice() {
    try {

        Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
        ReferenceType customerReferenceType = new ReferenceType();
        customerReferenceType.setName("abc");
        customerReferenceType.setValue("2");
        invoice.setCustomerRef(customerReferenceType);
        Line line = new Line();
        line.setAmount(new BigDecimal(15));
        line.setDetailType(LineDetailTypeEnum.SALES_ITEM_LINE_DETAIL);

        SalesItemLineDetail salesItemLineDetail = new SalesItemLineDetail();
        ReferenceType referenceType = customerReferenceType;
        referenceType.setName("Hours");
        referenceType.setValue("2");
        salesItemLineDetail.setItemRef(referenceType);
        line.setSalesItemLineDetail(salesItemLineDetail);

        List linesList = new ArrayList<Line>();
        linesList.add(line);
        invoice.setLine(linesList);

        this.service.add(invoice);
    } catch (FMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you tell me what the string "2" represents in the setValue for `ReferenceType`. Also, will the request fail if a customer does not exist in the account already i.e. is it necessary to create a customer entity before you can create an invoice for that customer? Will the system not create a new customer based on an invoice if they don't yet exist?

Comment: - 2 is the customerId which you get while creating the customer using API.In this case, after creating above invoice, service has returned 16 as InvoiceId. - Yes,customerId is mandatory(you're creating invoice against a customer)( Please refer docs ). - No system will not create a customer if it doesn't exist. You need to make a call to create a customer first then you need to pass the customerId(which u'll get as part of the response) in invoice create payload. Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear - if I'm creating an invoice for a customer that I didn't create with the API (but does exist), then would I have to first query the API for the customer (using a name or something else that I have to identify the customer) and then use ID returned in the response (if any) ?

Comment: Yes, correct. You can either query by Id or use the query endpoint with any allowed filterable(which attributes are filterable, that u'll get from docs) clause. - You can test this using ApiExplorer tool - https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO#Customer . A simple query by name ex - 'select * from Customer where DisplayName='abc'
Thanks